# Failed to decode downloaded font OTS parsing error: invalid version tag (fontawesome)

Tags: javascript, css, fonts

Site derekw.co

Hi! Because I had a very long list of modification to my parent theme's CSS, I dequeued it, and queued a new file.

I also changed the path of the Fontawesome files to make Chrome load it, but I see square boxes instead of my social media icons. In the console, it says that Chrome failed to decode the font, even though clicking on the file downloads it properly, and the preview shows the font being rendered properly.

The font works when I load my parent theme's stylesheet; it only doesn't work when I dequeue the parent sheet and only use the child theme's sheet, although the fonts are loaded properly (and show up in Google Inspect sources)

The font works fine on IE9, but not on Edge or Chrome

Any idea how to fix this?

EDIT:

Here's my code in CSS that downloads the font.

```
    @font-face {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    src: url(../theparagraph/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.6.3);
    src: url(../theparagraph/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.6.3) format('embedded-opentype'), url

(../theparagraph/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.6.3) format('woff2'), url(../theparagraph/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?

v=4.6.3) format('woff'), url(../theparagraph/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.6.3) format('truetype'), url

(../theparagraph/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.6.3#fontawesomeregular) format('svg');
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal
}
.fa {
    font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
    font-size: inherit;
    text-rendering: auto;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale
}
```

Chrome seems to be loading the fonts properly, as pictures
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/25yiJ.png):

Comment: Try to provide a little example code in order to let people more accurately help you.

Comment: @JoshKopen Thanks, I just uploaded the code and a screenshot of the resources loaded